# Can bindings create memory leaks in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, memory-leaks

Do I need to unbind items as the item disappears in order to prevent memory leaks? I guess I'm just a little worried that if I reload and a new template is applied to a control, and in that template there exists a binding to an outside element, could that prevent the control made for the template from being garbage collected?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you are not binding to a `DependencyProperty` or a object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` then the binding can leak memory, and you will have to unbind when you are done.

This is because if the object is not a `DependencyProperty` or does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` then it uses the `ValueChanged` event via the `PropertyDescriptors` `AddValueChanged` method. This causes the CLR to create a strong reference from the `PropertyDescriptor` to the `object` and in most cases the CLR will keep a reference to the `PropertyDescriptor` in a global table.

Because the binding must continue to listen for changes. This behavior keeps the reference alive between the `PropertyDescriptor` and the `object` as the target remains in use. This can cause a memory leak in the `object` and any `object` to which the `object` refers, This includes the data-binding target.

So in short if you are binding to a `DependencyProperty` or `INotifyPropertyChanged` object then you should be ok, otherwise like any subscribed event you should unsubscribe your bindings

---

**Edit:**
There is a possibility this was fixed in .NET4.5 using Weak Events/References, But after a few quick tests it seemed the same to me, I will have to dive in more deeply to confirm, so I'll personally say in **might** be fixed in 4.5 :)

Comment: @sa_ddam213: both the DP and INotifyPropertyChanged are safe for sure. Anyway, are you sure about the PD? I mean that the things should have turned fine on the latest .Net 4.5 framework, where the WeakEvent-pattern is used intensively.

Comment: I just double checked with .NET4.5 and it still seems to leak when PropertyDescriptor is used, If you want to confirm I used Jossef Goldberg's leak tested for WPF and recompiled to 4.5, link:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx, I have not tested to much into the leaks in 4.5 as the leaks in bindings in the previous framework versions changed my WPF coding habits permanently to avoid the issue :), I hope it is fixed and I will add disclaimer above about 4.5

Comment: What about bindings to ReadOnly properties? For example, binding to ExpressionBody member? public string Test => "TestString";

Comment: Note: the memory leak issue mentioned above only occurs when the binding mode is OneWay or TwoWay. If the binding is OneTime or OneWayToSource the CLR won't create a strong reference event if the bound property is not a DependencyProperty or if the bound object does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Would it possible to browse all the bindings in the visual tree of a user control, detect if there are the wrong kind and clear them ? Or why not clear all the binding whatever their kinds using BindingOperations.ClearBinding in the unload event. Or is stupid for some reason ?

Comment: It is not fixed. .NET Framework 4.7.1 has the same behavior.

Answer (score 13):

Not pretend to answer, just for reference. In a classic article on [`Finding Memory Leaks in WPF-based applications`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx) author *Jossef Goldberg*, described in detail cases, where there may be a memory leak in WPF application. Really, most relate to the .NET 3.5/4.0, but some cases may be relevant to this day. Also, have a small [extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/14/memory-leak-hotfixes-for-wpf-3-5-sp1.aspx).

Quote about leak in `Binding`:

`Cause:`

This leak documented in this [kb article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150309004920/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416). It is triggered because:

The `TextBlock` control has a binding to an object (myGrid) that has a reference back to the `TextBlock` (it is one of myGrid children’s).

`Note:` that this type of a DataBinding leak is unique to a specific scenario (and not to all DataBinding scenarios) as documented in the [kb article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150309004920/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416). The property in the `Path` is a not a `DependencyProperty` and not on a class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and in addition a chain of strong references must exist.

Code:

```
myDataBinding = new Binding("Children.Count");
myDataBinding.Source = myGrid; 
myDataBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
MyTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myDataBinding);
```

Same leaky code can be also written in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" 
           Text="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=Children.Count}" />
```

`Fix/Workaround:`

There are few of approaches, the easiest one is simply to clear the binding when the windows is about to close.

e.g.:

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(MyTextBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

Other approach is to set the mode of the data binding to OneTime. See the [kb article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150309004920/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416) for other ideas.

Useful link:

[Avoiding a WPF memory leak with DataBinding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micmcd/archive/2008/03/07/avoiding-a-wpf-memory-leak-with-databinding-black-magic.aspx)

Comment: Updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jgoldb/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications

Answer (score 8):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx, WPF uses Weak Event Patterns, which do not hold strong references to objects and allow them to be GC'ed if they are the only references to an object.

> "Many aspects of WPF data binding already have the weak event pattern
> applied in how the events are implemented."

But weak events are only used on `DependencyProperties` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` object, so if you are binding to a POCO with a binding mode other than `OneTime` you could end up leaking memory.

Comment: For future reference, POCO means "[Plain old CLR object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object)".