# How to Dispose resources when the WPF form close

Tags: wpf

When i tried to analyze my WPF (MVVM) application,it is found that after opening a page memory is increasd and at the time of close this page,it won't free that memory.So that the performance analyzer shows no decrease in resource at the time of form close.
After opening the particular page again,it is found that memor is again increase up to a level.It is still not disposing the memory.Please let me know if anyone know the reason.

Regards
Sreyas MN

Comment: The garbage collector does not necessarily free the memory immediately, if there is more than enough memory available. Try opening that page again and again, if the memory continues to rise until you get an OutOfMemory-Exception, you have a memory leak. Otherwise, there is most likely nothing wrong with this behaviour. Memory leaks *can* result in WPF from event handlers. If the page elements you remove hold event handlers to other parts that are not removed, this can prevent their memory from being freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sa_ddam answers this question quite well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542940/wpf-can-bindings-create-memory-leaks). Further down on the same page, there is a link to an [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx) that has a nice table of possible leak scenarios.

Finally, Redgate posted and nice article on what they believe are the [Top 5 memory leaks in WPF](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/WPF-silverlight-pitfalls).

I hope this helps.