# Does GC collect Binding Mode OneTime?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am wondering if `Binding` gets released/collected by `GC` when `Binding Mode` is `OneTime`?

`OneTime` just presists the value of the source to target and thats it. Like its name says its just useful that one time. Therefore to me it would make sense that the `Binding` object should get thrown away.

I am not sure, how could I test this?

Reason why I ask this is I am maintaining a `Binding` in code behind with `OneTime` Mode and I would avoid all those approaches like clear methods, clear bindings, setting the target property to `null`, setting the `Binding` instance to `null`, setting all references to `null`... and all that when GC will "hopefully" collect it automatically anyways.

Any experiences on this?

Comment: You could inspect your application with for example DotTrace Memory to check if the object will be collected or is a root.

Comment: I dont have dot trace and I am not sure if any memory profiling tool will allow me to spy on microsofts objects. Usually those tools allow you only your code but I am not sure. Do you have DotTrace? Can you test it? I would need valid licence for dot trace, right?

Comment: I own DotTrace and you can inspect the entire memory space of your application. You could download a trial version from JetBrains.

Comment: Ok I will see if I can get that trial version and a tutorial how to use DotTrace but still I am just thinking there are so many bindings in templates and styles of each control by default. Those tools usually create reports about all objects so even if I create a simple demo example I don't think I will be able to find that certain one with OneTime Mode in that mess. Could you test it if you have dot trace and you know how to use it? Post your results here please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OneTime just presists the value of the source to target and thats it. Like its name says its just useful that one time. Therefore to me it would make sense that the Binding object should get thrown away

If being more precise [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> OneTime updates the target property only when the application starts *`or when the DataContext undergoes a change`*.

This means that when changing `DataContext` property is also changing.

`OneTime` mode made ​​for those properties that have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and not need notification property when he is updated. It is also done to prevent *`memory leaks`* that can occur when using `Binding`.

I think the garbage collector makes no exception for this mode, because if he removes it from memory prematurely, switch the `DataContext` don't updates the properties.

*`Some useful links`*

[`A memory leak may occur when you use data binding in Windows Presentation Foundation`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us)

[`Finding Memory Leaks in WPF-based applications`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx)

[Can bindings create memory leaks in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542940/can-bindings-create-memory-leaks-in-wpf)