# With an MVVM Pattern (Specifically Using MVVM Light), How To Implement Model With More Than Just Primitives?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I am just getting started with the MVVM pattern, and have settled on using the MVVM Light toolkit for my Windows Phone app.

My question is this:

I am having trouble producing a view model that correctly binds a view to a model with properties that are more than just primitive types---what is a functioning way of structuring a model and accompanying view model such that a view will bind to the model through the view model, and properly update when values in the model change?

As in, how do I correctly reference the values of the model from the view model?

---

An example of this sort of model would be a class **Foo**, which has a property, *b*, that is a primitive, and another property, *a*, that is of type **Bar**, with its own properties---primitives or otherwise.

Foo:

```
public class Foo : ObservableObject
{

    public Foo()
    {

        a = new Bar();
    }

    public const string aPropertyName = "a";
    private Bar _a;
    public Bar a
    {
        get
        {
            return _a;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(aPropertyName, ref _a, value);
        }
    }

    public const string bPropertyName = "b";
    private bool _b;
    public bool b
    {
        get
        {
            return _b;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(bPropertyName, ref _b, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Bar:

```
public class Bar : ObservableObject
{

    public const string cPropertyName = "c";
    private bool _c;
    public bool c
    {
        get
        {
            return _c;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(cPropertyName, ref _c, value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: To clarify, when setting up the properties in the view model, should I be doing something like:

```
    public const string cPropertyName = "c";
    public bool c
    {
        get
        {
            return model.a.c;
        }
        set
        {

            model.a.c = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(cPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

or something different?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Have a private model instance in your ViewModel and expose the model properties through it. If you'd like to have other complex objects exposed, either expose its properties in the same ViewModel or create a new one.

Comment: There's no need to use a variable to hold the property name, imo. And I don't see why you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you are asking is **Nested vs Flat view model**. Both are correct approaches depending on the situation [though I prefer Nested View models]. 
I can't suggest you what you use, but in case of Foo-Bar example, wrapping up Bar's property with a property in Foo will make more sense [Flat View model approach]. So what u did by creating property c is right.

Below is my bit on both approaches

**Advantage of Nested View Model**

- That's what object oriented is all about.
- If you use LINQ to SQL or Entities, or an ORM, you can simply pass the ORM objects and not have to pass all kinds of properties.
- You can pass other views, so you can create separate models for partial views, and if that view uses a partial, you can pass the partial view model class as a property of the view model class.

**Advantage of Flat View Model**

- Keeps things simple and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In the last two WPF-applications we developed in our company, we used `MVVM` with `Caliburn.Micro`.

For the most of `ViewModels` we didn't create `Models`, because you should create a `Model` not because otherwise you will violate some OOP-rules, but because you need it.
When you should create a separated `Model`?

In two cases, in my opinion:

- when you can reuse a `Model` in the other application;
- when a `ViewModel` becomes complicated and you start to realize, that you want to simplify it by separating of concerns. Almost always, extracting a `Model` from a `ViewModel` is simple, if not trivial.

There is no sense to always create a `Model` for every `ViewModel`. Going this way, you overcomplicate a system, when you can avoid complications.

As to binding to a non-primitive type. Well, there is no any problems to add the support of notifying directly to the type.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your usage of ViewModel.

If you only need one or two properties of your complex type (`Bar` in your example), you can flatten it in your ViewModel. If you know you **always/mostly** need all of your complex properties, then it may make sense to create an own ViewModel for your complex model and expose your ViewModel instead of the model.

```
public class Foo : ObservableObject
{
    public BarViewModel A 
    {
        public const string aPropertyName = "a";
        private Bar _a;
        get
        {
            return _a;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(aPropertyName, ref _a, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least: 
Does your complex model needs two way binding? If no, you could just implement a property for your model.

But be warned! **Binding objects that do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` may result in memory leaks!** See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18543350/455493) answer