# Can binding ItemsControl to a non-ObservableCollection cause memory leaks?

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

While researching potential causes of memory leaks in WPF applications I came across this article:

https://oz-code.com/blog/net-c-tips/top-3-memory-leak-inducing-pitfalls-of-wpf-programming

This article makes the following unsubstantiated claim (which it admits to) that binding to collections other than `ObservableCollection` cause leaks:

> Avoid binding to collections that are not ObservableCollection
>
> ---
>
> I’m a bit sketchy on the details on this one. I haven’t yet been able
> to find the root cause of this issue, or find any corroborating blog
> post or MSDN articles, but still: in several instances, I’ve found
> memory leaks occurred when an ItemsControl was bound to an ICollection
> that isn’t an ObservableCollection, and changing it to an
> ObservableCollection solved the problem.

Is this an accurate statement? Or is there some other more likely explanation?

---

I wonder if what the OP described might have been caused by binding to objects that don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18543350/3195477).

Comment: Without any means to reproduce a potential issue, the statement does of course make no sense. IMO you can safely ignore it.

Comment: @clemens thanks it's good to hear this is, at the least, not a general problem. I'm tracking down some memory issues so one less thing to focus on.

Comment: Always keep in mind that there is a lot of garbage on the internet. There are many people that feel a need to inform the world of their knowledge, but who actually aren't any smarter than you or me. Just more talkative.

Comment: @Clemens which is why I asked about it here :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly quite what the OP asked, but close enough to help, I hope:  https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/ states:

> **Collection binding leak**
>
> A similar issue to the WPF binding leak is the
> Collection binding leak. If there is binding to a collection that does
> not implement the **INotifyCollectionChanged** interface, WPF creates a
> strong reference to this collection. As a result, it stays in memory
> for the entire application lifetime.