# Can I bind the visibility of a WPF ComboBox control to the presence/absence of items obtained from a Command?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

Can I bind the visibility of a WPF `ComboBox` control to the presence/absence of items obtained from a `Command` that populates the `ComboBox`’s `ItemsSource` property? In a nutshell, in a situation like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCommand.Result, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="..." />
```

Can I bind the value of the `Visibility` property to the presence or absence of items inside `MyCommand.Result` to hide/show it accordingly?

Comment: Yes, use IValueConverter

Comment: do you mean `if ItemsSource == null; comboBox.hide()` equivalent?

Comment: @LeiYang yes. My problem is that, when I debug, in the code-behind I get 0 as the `Count` property of `ComboBox.Items`.

Comment: you already said the word **bind**, but seems you try to do it in code-behind style. besides, i rarely see `MyCommand.Result`, where do you see such pattern and any benifits?

Comment: @LeiYang it’s code my company wrote some time ago...

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I tried `Visibility="{Binding MyCommand.Result, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"`, but the converter seems to be never called.

Comment: @PineCode does Result property implement PropertyChange? If not, then it won't get called. Additionally, you should probably consider is that - unless you implement it yourself for a custom collection - `Count` properties don't implement `PropertyChange`. Binding directly to that can cause a potentially nasty memory leak
(like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18543350/891715 ). Binding to Result and then using a converter is one of the ways to avoid that.

Comment: If you use a `Style` with a trigger that binds to `HasItems` as I suggested in my answer, you don't need to bother whether the source object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This solution is more generic as it works regardless of what source collection you bind to.

Comment: Does `MyCommand.Result` raise a `PropertyChanged` notification for `Result` at the end of the commands' Execute path, where the new value for Result is likely created/collected/assigned?

It's rare that Command implementation themself implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

EDIT Oups sorry @Arie hat the same thought a little earlier ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to a source property, e.g.:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCommand.Result, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyCommand.Result.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Or you could bind to the `HasItems` property of the control itself:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCommand.Result, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: The ComBox stays there, it doesn't disapper.

Comment: Using what code snipper? Try the second one? If the first one fails, it's an issue with your binding. The second one should work regardless. It does for me.