# WPF CollectionViewSource lost binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've made this exemple to repdouce my issue.

I've got a simple datagrid with a CollectionViewSource just for sort elements

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource 
            Source="{Binding _oNodeFolder.lImgs}" 
            IsLiveSortingRequested="True" 
            x:Key="LstImgsViewSourceKey"
            >
        
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <csm:SortDescription PropertyName="iNum"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

The first execution work fine and the order work properly if i add some items.
If anywhere in my code my object _oNodeFolder is set to null, I lost the binding and the sort order not work anymore.
But the items are correctly shown.

What I miss ?

I try to re set the CollectionViewSource.Source with code behind.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CollectionViewSource` isn't even holding the reference to `_oNodeFolder` object - it's holding the reference to its property: the `lImgs` collection. So even after you set `_oNodeFolder` to `null`, the `CollectionViewSource` is still holding the reference to that original `lImgs` collection, which in turn is probably holding the reference to its parent, and the GUI, too, is holding the reference to the `CollectionViewSource` itself through its `View` - thus the chain of references remains unbroken, and the 'old' items are still displayed, plus you have a potentially nasty memory leak.

You can't just set the parent object bound to the `Source` of the `CollectionViewSource` to `null` - that's not how it's supposed to work. You either:

- set and reset the `CollectionViewSource.Source` as needed in code-behind  (and potentially refresh the binding; sometimes setting it to `null` before setting it to the new value helps - personally I don't like this approach)
- never set the underlying source collection to null and only fill and clean it - which is the "default" way to use `CollectionViewSource`.

To have more control over my collection & how it's displayed (also from code-behind), plus to avoid the "accidental" memory leaks of the type explained above (where because one part of the chain of references wasn't disposed of, the entire chain of objects is still hanging in the memory potentially forever) I usually use a work-around if I only need one `View` on a collection:

```
public class ViewableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private ListCollectionView _View;

    public ViewableCollection(IEnumerable<T> items)
        : base(items) { }

    public ViewableCollection()
        : base() { }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ListCollectionView View
    {
        get
        {
            if (_View == null)
            {
                _View = new ListCollectionView(this);
                _View.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(InnerView_CurrentChanged);
            }
            return _View;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public T CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)this.View.CurrentItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this.View.MoveCurrentTo(value);
        }
    }

    private void InnerView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentItem"));
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ReplaceItems(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        this.Items.Clear();
        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void RemoveItems(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {

        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Remove(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ClearAll()
    {
        IList old = this.Items.ToList();
        base.Items.Clear();
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void CallCollectionChaged()
    {
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    // necessary for xml easy serialization using [XmlArray] attribute
    public static implicit operator List<T>(ViewableCollection<T> o)
    {
        return o == null ? default: o.ToList();
    }

    // necessary for xml easy serialization using [XmlArray] attribute
    public static implicit operator ViewableCollection<T>(List<T> o) 
    {
        return o == default || o == null ? new ViewableCollection<T>() : new ViewableCollection<T>(o);
    }
}
```

Then, let's assume I have a class like this (I'm skipping `PropertyChanged` implementation here for clarity):

```
public class VM_Persons
{
    public ViewableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public string NameFilter { get; set; }
    public VM_Perosns()
    {
        this.Persons.View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Country");
        this.Persons.View.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
        this.Persons.View.Filter = method_Filter;
        
        
    }

    private bool method_Filter(object item)
    {
        if (item == null) return false;

        if (item is Person p)
        {
            if (p.Name.Contains(NameFilter)) return true;
        }
    }
    
    public void LoadData(List<Person> list)
    {
        this.Persons.ReplaceItems(list);
    }
//....
}
```

In the GUI I'll bind to it like this (it's important to bind to the `View` property here):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons.View, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

This way, I have one view per one collection, and nothing holds leaky references I have no control over.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I'll try this now...

Comment: Your solution is generally right, but your problem analysis isn't. That's just not how bindings work, when you use dots in bindings (`_oNodeFolder.lImgs`) the *bound value* is the inner object, but all objects along the way have `PropertyChanged` handlers installed to react to changes, and that's including the outer object. Changing it will change the binding value.

Comment: @Bindy that's assuming _oNodeFolder has a PropertyChanged handler implemented. From the notation, it looks to me as a private field and not a property. I think the OP's case will still suffer from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18543350/891715 Although I wonder if this behavior got somehow fixed in the newer Frameworks?