# WPF DataGrid memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this code, and no matter what I do I keep getting a memory leak from the DataGrid data update. I've been looking at all the other answers to this problem here for days and I haven't found anything that works for me. I have a WPF window and this code to update the data (it is a small version of what happens in the real code, but I get the same bug).

I have this WPF code:

```
<Window x:Class="TremendoMemoryLeak.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TremendoMemoryLeak"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Hmis, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Estado">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Estado}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dato1" Binding="{Binding Dato1}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dato2" Binding="{Binding Dato2}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This class code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Datos> Hmis { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Datos>();
    private System.Threading.Timer timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(ActualizacionUI_Tick, null, 1000, 1000);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private void ActualizacionUI_Tick(object data)
    {
        Datos dato1 = new Datos() { Dato1 = "1", Dato2 = "2" };

        Datos dato2 = new Datos() { Dato1 = "1", Dato2 = "2" };

        Datos dato3 = new Datos() { Dato1 = "1", Dato2 = "2" };

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            dato1.Estado = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF5DC75D"));
            dato2.Estado = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF5DC75D"));
            dato3.Estado = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF5DC75D"));
            Hmis.Clear();
            Hmis.Add(dato1);
            Hmis.Add(dato2);
            Hmis.Add(dato3);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Hmis"));
        });
    }
}
```

And this data class:

```
public class Datos : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Brush Estado { get; set; }
    public string Dato1 { get; set; }
    public string Dato2 { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to dispose the SolidColorBrush

Comment: have you tried EnableColumnVirtualization = true
EnableRowVirtualization = true in the grid. and use ItemsSource="{Binding yourlist, IsAsync=True}"

Comment: @CodeFromItaly `SolidColorBrush` are not `IDisposable`

Comment: @CodeFromItaly I have tried to do it without SolidColorBrush and it still happens the same way.

Comment: @Tan is still the same

Comment: @sneik15 how much data are we talking about? afew 1000s rows or more?

Comment: @Tan as stated in the code, 3 rows that get updated continuously

Comment: @sneik15 but you not updating the data. you are initializing new objects every second. maybe thats why

Comment: @Tan This is an example application, what happens in the real code is that I get through a socket the new data in a new object, so I need to delete the previous ones and add the new ones, but I have tried and even just updating the values of the class it still happens when deleting and adding. Finally, if I update the data of the objects and do a DataGrid.Items.Refresh(); so that the change is reflected in the interface, the memory leak still happens.

Comment: How do you know that it's a memory leak?

Comment: Use the Visual Studio profiler to find out where the memory leak, if any, comes from.

Comment: @Evk if you pay attention to the debugger when executing the application, you can see the memory usage rising without the garbage collector being able to clear it at all

Comment: @aybe I have already done it and I see that where the memory is being lost is in the datagrid, but I don't know how to stop it from happening.

Comment: To maximize your chances of getting help, you should post a minimal, verifiable and complete example. If that example does not exhibit such leak, then most certainly there's something on your code that slipped in.

Comment: Memory usage rising doesn't mean it's a memory leak. Garbage collector might not reclaim memory if it feels like there is no need to. Especially under debugger. Add something like `GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);` in your tick function and then see if memory rises without bounds.

Comment: @aybe if you create a new WPF solution and you add the code I posted, you will clearly see the memory leak happening

Comment: Maybe you should look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542940/can-bindings-create-memory-leaks-in-wpf/18543350#18543350

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek I had already seen this answer and applied what it says, but the memory leak still occurs.

Comment: @Evk I tried GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced); and it still happens

Comment: From your example I didn't see memory leaks. Even if I add 10000 `Datos` through `for` loop at each tick. As suggested, you should use VS Profiler to detect where memory leaks (if it leaks really).

Comment: @Auditive If I run exactly that code, memory leak occurs (.Net 5) Full solution: https://fromsmash.com/FullSolution

Comment: Still nothing, even on your full solution. Average memory usage in Task Manager after 5 min run ~54-56 Mb

Comment: Could you make a little capture for us of VS Profiler?

Comment: @Auditive I noticed I was running it on VS2022 and I tried running it on VS2019 and it worked, so it seems to be a VS2022 specific bug. Thank you all for your help

Comment: Since you are only executing UI related code in the timer callback, you should use the [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#examples) instead. The DispatcherTimer will automatically execute the callback on the Dispatcher (that is associated with the timer - usually the UI thread'S Dispatcher). The invocation of the PropertyChanged event for the `Hmis` property is redundant as the property itself never changes. You only change the collection' s values.

Comment: Raising the event periodically (without any purpose) can impact the applications perfomance negatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was executing the solution on Visual Studio 2022, and upon testing it on VS2019, the memory leak is suddenly gone, so it seems to be an issue in the 2022 preview.

Comment: Glad to hear. It's worth to report this issue to team who is working on Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: I would still re use 3 brushes rather than instantiating per item if this is what you do in the production code.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the timer period to 50 ms and run the program in debug for 80mn (~100 000 calls to `ActualizacionUI_Tick`) the memory usage is stable and around 123mb.

When you start the application there is indeed a period of time where the memory usage increase (and then it stabilize). Using JetBrains dotMemory it appears that the surviving objects are related to `ConditionalWeakTable` implementation and retained by the `MS.Internal.WeakEventTable` which is [cleaned-up](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/MS/Internal/WeakEventTable.cs,220) once in awhile on the will of some internal heuristic.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, but I just detected that the bug was because of the version of visual studio I used