# How can I set ComboboxItem isEnable property with binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a model view and a property called isEnable and I would like to set the comboboxItem IsEnable property with binding to property created in the model view , the problem is that I have datatemplate created inside a combobox , so it's not a simple Combobox , this is my code:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" Grid.Row="3" Height="30"  Margin="10,5,5,5">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image />
            <TextBlock />
        </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsEnable" Value="{Binding IsEnable}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Simple Class of Users:

```cs
public class Users 
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnable { get; set; }

    public Users()
    {

    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It's been a while since I did anything with WPF, but I'm pretty sure you can't just bind your `ItemsSource` to a class, rather you'll have to bind it to a property, and that property has to be a list or collection of some sort, then bind to properties of the class of that collection like `{Binding Path=IsEnable}`

Comment: Yes , I did this , it's a collection ( list )

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding this code :

```
 <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem"
        <Setter Property="IsEnable" Value="{Binding IsEnable}" />
     </Style>
 </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

So the complete code will be :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" Grid.Row="3" Height="30"  Margin="10,5,5,5">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image />
            <TextBlock />
        </StackPanel>
         <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" >
                <Setter Property="IsEnable" Value="{Binding IsEnable}" />
            </Style>
         </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: The class does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` so any property changes will not be reflected on the UI. If you leave it like this, you may want to change the binding mode to `OneTime` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Could you please tell me more about `OneTime` mode ( give more details )?

Comment: Do some research, there are plenty of resources online that will explain it better than me. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542940/can-bindings-create-memory-leaks-in-wpf