# HwndHost leaks memory

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, hwnd, hwndhost

we have an external video player to which i need to give a reference to a HwndHost, and then the external video player renders into it.

all works fine, but i cant find out why memory is leaked, as new HwndHosts are created.

here is my HwndHost implementation:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Windows.Interop;

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public class MediaFoundationVideoHost : HwndHost, IDisposable
    {
        internal const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
        internal const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        internal const int LBS_NOTIFY = 0x00000001;
        internal const int SS_NOTIFY = 0x00000100;
        internal const int SS_BLACKFRAME = 0x00000007;
        internal const int SS_WHITERECT = 0x00000006;
        internal const int HostId = 0x00000002;
        internal const int LISTBOX_ID = 0x00000001;
        internal const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;
        internal const int GC_ALLGESTURES = 0x00000001;
        internal const int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;
        internal const int WS_DISABLED = 0x8000000;

        private HandleRef handleRef;
        private IntPtr hwndHost;
        private IntPtr parentHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        private readonly object lockObj = new object();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr child, IntPtr parent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateWindowEx", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(int extendedWindowStyle,
                                                     string classname,
                                                     string windowname,
                                                     int style,
                                                     int x,
                                                     int y,
                                                     int width,
                                                     int height,
                                                     IntPtr hwndParent,
                                                     IntPtr menu,
                                                     IntPtr instance,
                                                     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object param);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DestroyWindow", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            lock (this.lockObj)
            {
                handleRef = new HandleRef(null, IntPtr.Zero);
                parentHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                hwndHost = IntPtr.Zero;
                
                base.Dispose(disposing);
              
            }
        }

        protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
        {
            this.hwndHost = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.parentHandle = hwndParent.Handle;

            int style = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BLACKFRAME | SS_WHITERECT;
            style |= SS_NOTIFY;


            this.hwndHost = CreateWindowEx(0,
                                           "static",
                                           string.Empty,
                                           style,
                                           0,
                                           0,
                                           (int)200,
                                           (int)200,
                                           hwndParent.Handle,
                                           (IntPtr)HostId,
                                           IntPtr.Zero,
                                           0);


            this.handleRef = new HandleRef(this, this.hwndHost);
            return this.handleRef;
        }

        protected override void DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef hwnd)
        {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd.Handle);

        }

      
        protected override IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam, ref bool handled)
        {
            handled = false;
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        }
    }
}
```

i create these 25 of HwndHosts in my MainWindow(wpf), and then i dispose them, hoping they get released and no memory leaks:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<MediaFoundationVideoHost> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MediaFoundationVideoHost>();
        private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {

                Thread.Sleep(200);
                for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
                {
                    var videoHost = new MediaFoundationVideoHost();
                    Items.Add(videoHost);
                }

                foreach (var item in Items)
                {
                    item.Dispose();
                }
                Items.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="Black" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"></ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

my program goes from 50mb to 400mb in like 60 minutes, and i cant find anything useful while analyzing the dump of the process. BuildWindowCore is called, and DestroyWindowCore is called aswell.

thankies

Comment: You need to analize and provide more information about objects in heap after complete Dispose() - Gen1, Gen2. Probably when you add instances to ObservableCollection.. when  GC trying to mark not used objects it decided that they are are refferenced.. and move it to Gen1 -> Gen2... and as you know such objects will stay in memory till the process will be terminated. Call Dispose not release memory in heaps immediatelly.. some objects may survive after GC.

Comment: i tried this even without ObservableCollections, by adding my MediaFoundationVideoHost directly into my grid.children. when i analyzed the dump, i see 130000 of these objects, each one of them attached only to FinalizerQueue and nothing else. this should mean its ready to be GCed and have its memory released, right?

Comment: If objects in FinalizerQueue.. probably in finalizer of MediaFoundationVideoHost throw some exception.

MediaFoundationVideoHost is not implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.. probably it is related to know problem when WPF create hard link to the object.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542940/can-bindings-create-memory-leaks-in-wpf)