# Potential Memory Leak with INotifyPropertyChanged and Command Binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following class structure in a WPF application:

```
class A {
    public B BProperty { get; set; }
    
    public A()
    {
        BProperty = new B();
    }
}

class B : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public string Display { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

In my WPF view, I'm using class A as a DataContext and binding a button's command to the DoSomethingCommand of the BProperty:

```
<Button Command="{Binding BProperty.DoSomethingCommand}"></Button>
```

The class A will be initialized on a Window open event.

I was getting a memory leak when opening and closing the Window multiple times.
The problem was that class A doesn't inherit the "INotifyPropertyChanged" interface, while class B does.

But I don't know why that can be a problem. Could someone explain to me the issue here?

Comment: Well, your A instance is holding a reference to your B instance.  Under normal circumstances any object implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` would go out of scope and be disposed when the form using it closes.  But that doesn't have anything to do with INotifyPropertyChanged. There's nothing special about the INotifyPropertyChanged interface itself that would confer magical garbage collection properties.

Comment: How do you know that a) you get a memory leak and b) it's leaking for not implementing IPNC?

Comment: Consider removing setters of properties that won't change after initialization.
Consider using Binding-Mode `OneTime` for the Command (usually commands are built on construction and then rest immutable)

Comment: Why not just implement inpc in A?

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/products/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/WPF-silverlight-pitfalls

Comment: @lidqy the problem is fixed after I implemented IPNC

Comment: @lidqy I was getting memory leak exceptions and I debugged it using dotMemory from jetbrains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can bindings create memory leaks in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542940/can-bindings-create-memory-leaks-in-wpf)